# ALTER TABLE add new column and make it Unique in combination with an existing column

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to add a new column into table and create a unique key constraint with that column and another already existing column

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using two DDL statements:

1. Add the new column:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN newcolumn INTEGER
   ```
2. Add uniqueness constraint for the new column in combination with an existing one:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT myuniqueness UNIQUE KEY (newcolumn, oldcolumn)
   ```

Comment: Note that the new column will be filled with NULL initially, if it has no DEFAULT. This is fine, but the UNIQUE constraint won't be very useful.